# Laravel Query Builder with CONCAT and DATE_FORMAT giving errorr

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query like below:

```
$events = Event::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(title," : ", DATE_FORMAT(date,"%M %d %Y") AS event'), 'id')->where('club_id', '=', \Auth::guard('web_club')->user()->id)->where('date','>',date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-2days")))->orderBy('date','asc')->pluck('event', 'id');
```

I am trying to format the datetime into a more legible format but keep getting the error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `events` where `club_id` = ? and `date` > ? order by `date` asc' at line 1 (SQL: select CONCAT(title," : ", (DATE_FORMAT(date,"%M %d %Y")) AS event, `id` from `events` where `club_id` = 75 and `date` > 2020-03-13 order by `date` asc) "
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong at all or alternative methods to achieve the same result?

Comment: what is  ?? I don't think this kind of data sql allow.

Comment: As far as I am aware, its an 'emoji' and it gets stored and retreived from my database so far without any issues. I stumbled accross it accidentaly. It comes in very handy for especially  for an application targetted at millennials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a bracket near here which was responsible for the error.

```
 DATE_FORMAT(date,"%M %d %Y"))
```